# FFMpeg - Video conversion - .OGG to .MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ogg

After scouring the net, I can't find anyone else trying to do this:
Convert an OGG video format to MP4 video (usualy people are doing this the other way round).
I have FFMpeg working just fine converting WEBM to MP4 but it just doesn't seem to like OGG files.
The official FFMpeg documentation says that it can both Encode AND Decode OGG files but for some reason it isn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: ffmpeg should have no problems doing this. Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: already answered below, thanks.

Comment: What is meant is that you shouldn't need to rename a file for ffmpeg to convert it. It should work fine with ogg, oga, ogv, etc. It's why I wanted to see the command and log so I can see what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

AHA, found the following in wikipedia:

Before 2007, the .ogg filename extension was used for all files whose content used the Ogg container format. Since 2007, the Xiph.Org Foundation recommends that .ogg only be used for Ogg Vorbis audio files. The Xiph.Org Foundation decided to create a new set of file extensions and media types to describe different types of content such as .oga for audio only files, **.ogv for video** with or without sound (including Theora), and .ogx for multiplexed Ogg.[4]

So, any ogg video has to have the .ogv extension - not older .ogg extension for FFMpeg to convert it.

It works! :)